# Session doesnt work in an iframe on IE 11, with a java servlet inside a wordpress

Tags: html, internet-explorer, session, servlets, iframe

I have a server Unix+Apache+php with a wordpress v4. There i have the webpage A
In the other hand, i have a server Unix+Apache+Tomcat+Java1.6 (a java servlet). There i have the webpage B

In the page A there is an iFrame wich include the webpage B. That webpage B opens a new session and does some registration forms.
The problem is that it works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't work on Interent Explorer. When the session is created by the java server, is like IE don't recognize it.

I saw that someone with a similar problem solved it tuning both servers on the same time space. It didnt work for me. Any suggestions? thanks in advance!

Comment: If you click Tools > Internet Options > Privacy and drag the slider to the bottom ("Accept all cookies") does the problem go away? If so, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/17/simple-introduction-to-p3p-cookie-blocking-frame.aspx

Comment: @EricLaw sorry, yes it doesn't use a separate process so its not that.

Comment: Is this specifically version 11?

Comment: @EricLaw a lot of thanks for your answer; If I do this it works perfectly, but the problem is that i can't ask the users to quit the Internet Explorer security level, since the most of them use public PC's on schools.

Comment: @Dreamwalker, yes, we only need it runing on IE 11

Comment: @VíctorMañas: The fact that adjusting the slider fixes it strongly suggests that your problem is lack of a P3P response header. The link I shared explains the problem and how to fix it.